# opening a file on a button click

Tags: java, file

I have java project in which a button opens a pdf file 
when the project was exported to runnable jar the file don't open !!

that's my button listener

```
public void about (Event event){

    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        try {
            File myFile = new File("src/application/Documenation.pdf");
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // no application registered for PDFs
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never reference content within the `src` directory, when you project is built, the `src` directory will not exist.

Content contained within your application context (particularly those which are included within a Jar file) can't normally be accessed as a `File` (like you do from the file system), they become an entry within you applications Jar file.

In this case, you will need to extract the file before you can open it.

What you can do is, get use `Class#getResourceAsStream` and copy the resulting `InputStream` to the disk

For example...

```
try (InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/application/Documenation.pdf")) {
    File file = File.createTempFile("Documentation", ".pdf");
    file.deleteOnExit();
    try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```